# Remove string and replace a new string with format

Tags: command-line

Here is I want: I have a `.doc` file which consists of many lines. In the file I need to find a string and replace it with another string. Up to this fine. But how can I replace the string with another string along with format. I mean like **Bold**, *Italic*, Underline, etc. for new string.

Comment: @Radu Thanks you. ( I cant type your name completely.those spec char are not in my KB)

Comment: My documents will be opened with ms word libre word processors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I would know how to automate `.doc` files is with a very elaborate and extremely time consuming Python script. You would need to automate [Libre|Open]Office using PyUNO.

This is the *best* way to do this because you can use just about every function in Office without having to do dodgy hacks...

---

A less ideal method would be using `unoconv` to convert the `.doc` to something human-readable like `.fodt`, then `sed` and the convert it back to `.doc`.

```
unoconv -o test.fodt -f fodt test.doc
sed -i 's/string/newstring/g'
unoconv -o test.doc -f doc test.doc
```

You have to be careful that your string isn't going to interfere with the document tags. If it is, you'll need to use something a lot more industrial to make sure you're only editing things in `<text:...>` tags.

So instead of using `.fodt`, you can use html

```
unoconv -o test.html -f html test.doc
sed -i 's/string/<B>newstring</B>/g'
unoconv -o test.doc -f doc test.html
```

However, there is every chance the conversion will completely munch the document formatting.

Comment: Master one doubt ..what about special symbols and table's data if convertion to be done

Comment: Then all bets are off. If it's any consolation, you can take a look at one of the fodt/html pages to see exactly what you're dealing with but documents are trickier things than most people give them credit.